# behaviours of Val in Scala

Tags: scala

I am getting the error when trying to execute the below code from Eclipse because I can't reassign Val, right?

```
object Test {
    def main(args: Array[String]){
      val tempVal = 100;

      val checkval = if (tempVal > 50) 1 else 0

      println("The new value is: " + checkval);

      //Getting Error Below
      checkval1 = if (tempVal > 200) 0

    }
}
```

Now when I am trying to do the same thing from command line, why I am not getting the same error?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the REPL, every statement you type will be wrapped inside of an object which is nested inside the object of the previous statement. This is done specifically so that you can "change" the value of `val`s or `class`es or `trait`s later. Otherwise you would have to restart the REPL and retype every statement everytime you make a typo.

So, your REPL session is (roughly) compiled to something like this:

```
object Line1 {
  val x = 100
  println(x)

  object Line2 {
    val y = if (x < 50) 1 else 0
    println(y)

    object Line3 {
      val y = if (x < 50) 0 else 1
      println(y)
    }
    val _ = Line3 // force creating the Line3 object
  }
  val _ = Line2 // force creating the Line2 object
}
val _ = Line1 // force creating the Line1 object
```

Since Scala has nested scopes, `Line3`'s `y` can shadow `Line2`'s `y`.

Comment: That explains me the design clearly. Very good explanation. Thanks @Jörg.

Answer (score 8):

You're not doing **the same** -- you just redefined (shadowed*) val, not reassigned new value to it. If you write `y = if (x < 50) 0 else 1` instead of `val y = if (x < 50) 0 else 1` you will get the error as well.

[image]

* this is only possible in REPL

Comment: Thanks. It means every time I will redefine val with the same name, it will shadow the previous val, right?

Comment: @SudiptaDeb: Not in normally compiled code (you still won't be able to do this). However, the REPL allows you to rebind the `val`.

Comment: @TheTerribleSwiftTomato: Exactly when I am trying to do the same thing from Eclipse, it is not allowing me to write the code itself. But in REPL it is executing make a shadow of the previous val.

Comment: In the REPL, every statement you type will be wrapped inside of an object which is nested inside the object of the previous statement. This is done specifically so that you can "change" the value of `val`s or `class`es or `trait`s later. Otherwise you would have to restart the REPL and retype every statement everytime you make a typo.